# Can we connect to the socket server that is on the different network?

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

Excuse me, I am a beginner to networking here.

I am trying to connect to my friend's network. She is approximately 10 kilometers from me. I am the client and she is the server that I want to connect and send messages.

I tried to connect two computers on my own LAN. It worked!, but when I change internet of another laptop to mobile hotspot and try to connect to that laptop. Of course, different IP. It doesn't work anymore!

My questions are:

- Is it possible to connect to one or more remote computers that are on the different internet provider or network using python socket module?
- Is it possible to receive and send messages between a computer on WIFI LAN and a computer on WIFI mobile hotspot using python socket module?
- What do I probably need to make the connection?

Comment: That's possible with port forwarding or VPN. But both are not a Stack Overflow topic.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ISPs, there's just one Internet that all the ISPs are part of.

Comment: @Barmar not true with CGNAT

Comment: Look up "port forwarding"

Answer (score 0):

- Yes.
- Yes.
- Ensure that your friend's server has a routable IP address.

If your client is attempting to connect
across the public internet
to an rfc1918 [private address](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918#section-3),
it will fail in the way you reported.
You need to ensure the client is
connecting to a reachable server IP.
It must be routable,
and there must not be a firewall in between
which filters and discards your packets.